# Gap Year in Resume

Tags: employment-gaps

I am looking for a job and therefore I am updating my CV. The problem I am handling is that my CV has a gap year (2008-2009) in the past and I do not know how to deal with it. During that year I have travelled and studied to apply for Masters and I do not know how to report it considering that I have sections as "Professional Experience" and "Education".
How should I report my gap year and in which section of my résumé?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't have to report anything. Put the gap in there in plain sight and let them come to you and ask you about it at interview time. Then you can say that you travelled and studied for your Master's degree - as you were not doing time in the Big House, you'll be fine :)

Comment: see also: [Handling a Gap in Your Résumé (Travel experience)](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3692/handling-a-gap-in-your-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-travel-experience)